# MS Teams open dialog with Window.open, without valid domain

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, microsoft-teams

We are working on MS Teams Application in which we need to do authentication with third party identity server. Currently, when we enter the third-party domain in "**Valid Domain**" list it works as expected in both MS Teams Desktop and MS Teams Web application. Please find our sample code as follow,

```
microsoftTeams.initialize(() => {
    microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
        url: ds['Url'],
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        failureCallback: function (reason) {
          window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Our issue is we do have 1000+ third-party services with which we need to authorize as per the end user's preference, and it is not possible to list all the domains in a "Valid Domain" list. So, as an alternative we have tried with,

```
window.open(ds['Url']);
```

**windows.open()** works well for both MS Teams Desktop and MS Teams Web application but **we are working with SPA so, after redirection we would like to close that window which we are not able to do so from our SPA.**

Comment: Hi @Pratik Ratanpara, We are working on it practically and checking with our internal Team and will update soon.

Comment: Hi @Pratik Ratanpara, are you getting any error ?, can you please share the error details with us, are you using SPA as tab ?

Comment: Hello @Jagadeesh-MSFT, Thanks for the reply.

Yes, We are using SPA.
No, We are not able to get any errors. While opening a task dialog in MS Teams app, It will render html page.  But without providing the valid domain in Microsoft Teams app configuration, that html page will not display.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To Render HTMl page inside teams the Site domain should be added in the valid domain section. A list of valid domains for websites the app expects to load within the Teams client. This is by design. Please check [Valid-domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/content-page#valid-domains) for more info.

Comment: If exist a way to make popup window same as in Team popup out app button. Window.open is openening new browser window. We need it as part of MS Teams Desktop